# "I have been assigned" vs. "I am assigned"

Tags: tenses, sentence, syntactic-analysis

Below are the 2 ways to compose a sentence to convey that a task is assigned to me by my Manager. This task was assigned to me yesterday & still  on my list/

> I have been assigned to the task

Or

> I am assigned to the task.

Which above the 2 is better & why?

Comment: difference in aspect

Comment: Both are passive forms - the first becomes "Someone has assigned me to the task"  in active voice; and the second "Someone assigns me to the task." Meanings differ according to the tense(s).

Answer (score 2):

> I have been assigned to the task

This refers to your being assigned at some time in the past and indicates from the context that you are still assigned.

> I am assigned to the task.

This refers to your current state.

> Which above the 2 is better & why?

Neither, both are fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to choose between the two, I would opt for, "I have been assigned to the task".  It suggests an ongoing commitment to the task.  "I am assigned to the task" has a slight suggestion of being only for the current point in time - eg yesterday someone else was assigned to it and tomorrow another person will be.

But personally I would say, "The task has been assigned to me".

Comment: How about using "A" instead of "The" as following,

"A task has been assigned to me".

Answer (score 0):

If you are not aware which task you have been assigned then placing
"A" would sound good.Whereas if you use "The" it strongly emphasizes on a particular task , where the speaker is absolutely aware of the task  and his willingness to complete it.